# Can I use the CardView widget on Android 4.x-devices?

Tags: android

The Android L SDK contains backporting of the widgets, as far as I understand. Hence the `com.android.support:cardview-v7`-library. How do I set up `build.gradle` so that I can run apps on v19/20 (4.4.x) while using the `CardView` widget?

I've tried adding this to the dependency:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:+'
```

while having the following in the `android`-section:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "20"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 'L'
    }
}
```

...but this results in

```
Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':vg3-main:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 19 cannot be smaller than version L     declared in library com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.0-rc1
```

...which I don't understand because I'm not referencing `support-v4`

Any takers?

Comment: The L support libraries are locked to L as long as L is just a developer preview. They are already compatible down to API level 7, but still the min SDK level is set to L for the time being. However there are a few things you can do to use it below L anyway. You can for example manually edit all build.gradle files to remove the min SDK restriction. Or you can force a min SDK level of 7 with the manifest merger.

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll just stick to L-devices for now then.